# Correct syntax to add scripted fields within Kibana

Tags: kibana, kibana-4

Given the following object type:

```
class Test {
   string name;
   int number;
}
```

what is the correct syntax to add scripted fields within Kibana which:

- sum the value of all numbers for all Test objects in an index
- get the average value of the number field for all Test objects
- sum the value of all numbers for Test objects with a specific name

I have tried various things, but each time Kibana locks up.

The correct syntax for even the simplest scripted object will help. If anyone knows how to solve any of the above it would be especially appreciated, thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Here's a really really simple scripted field (this syntax works)

```
doc['your_numeric_field'].value + 33
```

I'm not really used scripted fields, but I think it can process the data within the record and won't aggregate multiple record's data. Correct me if I'm wrong, but I saw examples for that.

[*" use scripts to combine several fields, or perform math on number fields, and then drop the result into a visualization. "*](https://www.elastic.co/blog/kibana-4-beta-3-now-more-filtery)